# If I push an update to GitHub, will it push to Heroku?

Tags: github, heroku

I was just wondering when I connected my GitHub repo to a Heroku, if I push updates to GitHub, would the updates automatically be sent to Heroku as well? Or is it so if I push to Heroku it will go to GitHub?

Comment: it will if you set heroku pipeline well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, Github updates can be configured to automatically push to heroku.

You may need the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install) to make things easier.

Follow instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) to push Github updates to your heroku app.

Comment: Links are great when they support answers, but they shouldn't be required reading. [Answers should stand on their own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/248627). Please [edit] your answer to include enough detail so as to be useful without the links.